# Unity c#: How to slow down rotation over time?

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, rigidbody

I am making a space combat game, in which the player can press q and e to roll their ship. I did this by adding torque to the rigid body when the player press q or e. However, after they do so, they keep on rotating. How do i make the angular velocity slowly go back to zero?

I tried using angular drag, but that does not work.

```
public float TurnSpeed;

public Rigidbody rb;

float currentturn;

Vector3 turn;

float turnEnabler;

bool iszero;

public float dampener;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    rb.AddTorque(new Vector3(0, 0, turnEnabler));

    if (Input.GetKey("e"))
    {
        turnEnabler -= TurnSpeed;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey("q"))
    {
        turnEnabler += TurnSpeed;
    }

    rb.angularDrag = dampener;


}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Tom mentioned, after your second if call, you might have a third if statement such as:

`else if(!Input.GetKey("e") && !Input.GetKey("q")){turnEnabler /= 2;}`

Note that checking for 'q' again is redundant but might be helpful for completeness or readability if desired.

Also, since dividing by 2 will take a long time to really get to zero, you can (if you're bored) throw in something along the lines of:

`if(turnEnabler <= 0.01 && turnEnabler >= -0.01){turnEnabler = 0.00}`

Answer (score 1):

From your example, at the end of `Update`, you can do something like

```
turnEnabler /= 2;
```

This would halve the rotating speed every frame, until it eventually reaches 0.

Depending on what kind of behavior you want, you can also try similar changes to the `turnEnabler` variable, like adding a fixed number every frame.